# Multiple COUNT on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table:

```
   +----------+-----------+----------+--------+
    | id       |  winnerId | loserId  | gameId |
    +----------+-----------+----------+--------+
    | 1        | user1     | user2    |      1 |
    | 2        | user2     | user1    |      1 |
    | 3        | user1     | user2    |      1 |
    | 4        | user1     | user2    |      2 |
      5          user1       user3           1
    +----------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

actually i have more columns in table but they are unreleated but please consider that

Given winnerId,loserId and gameId i would like to get total scores(win count) of winner and loser players **against each other**

Example query input:

```
winnerId:user1
loserId:user2
gameId:1
```

Result:

```
   --userId--totalScore--
       user1      2           
       user2      1
```

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use COUNT().

Comment: What relevance do the winner/loser ID have? It looks like you've just given the number of wins per user for gameId 1 i.e `SELECT winnerId, count(*) FROM t WHERE gameid = 1 GROUP BY winnerId` - it produces your output and doesn't use the userIDs at all

Comment: i would like to get win counts of 2 players against each other. i added one more row to example data to explain better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the rows where the two players played against each other. Then count the rows per winner for the game:

```
select winnerid, count(*) 
from mytable
where gameid = 1
and (winnerid, loserid) in ((1,2), (2,1))
group by winnerid;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=976df92c9706c08d34a1c372735efa4c

**EDIT:** If one of the players never won against the other, there will be no row to count. If you want to see a result row with a count of zero in that case, then you must first create a row. One way is this:

```
select playerid, sum(won) 
from 
(
  select winnerid as playerid, 1 as won
  from mytable
  where gameid = 1
  and (winnerid, loserid) in ((1,2), (2,1))
  union all 
  select loserid as playerid, 0 as won
  from mytable
  where gameid = 1
  and (winnerid, loserid) in ((1,2), (2,1))
)
group by playerid
order by playerid;
```

Comment: sorry for bad explanation i edited my question. i am trying to get win counts of winner and loser players against each other.

Comment: This is what `and (winnerid, loserid) in ((1,2), (2,1))` accomplishes.

Comment: what is in (1,2),(2,1) ? i am having empty result. maybe because i have some unreleated other columns ?

Comment: Another way of writing `and ((winnerid = 1 and loserid = 2) or (winnerid = 2 and loserid = 1))`.

Comment: this does not produce the result i want. it just has winner and his win count. i need userId column and totalScore column which shows score of each player against each other. your query above produces this result: http://prntscr.com/rp0re2  can you please check my desired result again

Comment: Then you made a mistake. See this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=976df92c9706c08d34a1c372735efa4c

Comment: oh i realized that if there is no win it doenst count it as 0. is it possible to implement it

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I've updated my answer with one possible solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like aggregation and filtering:

```
select winnerId as userId, count(*) as num_wins
from t
where ? in (winnerId, loserId) and
      ? in (winnerId, loserId) and
      gameId = ?
group by winnerId
```

Comment: i would like to get win counts of 2 players against each other. i added one more row to example data to explain better